# How to insertAdjacentHTML if in the string to insert there is variable from JavaScript? The string doesn't take the value of ${groupId}

Tags: javascript, html, interpolation, insertadjacenthtml

This is my HTML:

```
<li><a href="/Simpson.html">
  <div class="item-row">
<!-- I WANT TO insertAdjacentHTML HTML HERE  -->
    <div id= "simpsons" class="item-infos">
      <h2>Simpson</h2>
        <p> <strong>6 members</strong> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a></li>
```

This is the code I tried to use with the insertAdjacentHTML:

```
let groupId = 1; 
let addGroup = document.querySelector("#simpsons");
addGroup.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<img class="img-circle" src= `http://download.images.com/meetandcode/2020/images/groups/${groupId}.png`>");
```

Comment: it should work !! , but as a workaround you could do as , take a new variable as let srcURL = `http://download.images.com/meetandcode/2020/images/groups/${groupId}.png`

Comment: i have edited please check

Comment: Hi, ok, this is the code I will use to set the srcURL---->
let srcURL = `http://download.runtastic.com/meetandcode/mobile_and_web_2016/images/groups/${groupId}.png`
But after this, I have to use the insertAdjacentHTML and I have the same problem as before. Look at here:
addGroup.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<img class="img-circle" src = ${srcURL}");

Comment: Hi, I've seen the edited answer but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I think the issue is you are using double (`"`) to enclose both the html and the `class` attribute value, this confuses the browser as it cant determine where the element is ending. Change either one of it to single (`'`) quote.

```js
let addGroup = document.querySelector("#simpsons");
addGroup.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<img class='img-circle' src= http://download.images.com/meetandcode/2020/images/groups/${groupId}.png>");
```

```html
<li><a href="/Simpson.html">
  <div class="item-row">
<!-- I WANT TO insertAdjacentHTML HTML HERE  -->
    <div id= "simpsons" class="item-infos">
      <h2>Simpson</h2>
        <p> <strong>6 members</strong> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a></li>
```